# Let typescript infer the type of of a class method, implementing an interface

Tags: typescript

In our application, I would like it to be optional to have to define method arguments, if those are known from a parent:

```js
interface Parent<T> {

    foo(arg1: T): void;

}

class MyImpl implements Parent<string> {
    foo(arg1) {

    }
}
```

Currently this throws an error:

```
Parameter 'arg1' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I'm curious if there's a way to avoid this error.

The real-world use-case is a lot more complex, and making the argument type optional avoids a bunch of quite complicated type juggling.

There's other places in Typescript where it *can* infer, specifically:

```js
type Callback = (s:string) => void;

function foo(cb: Callback) {
  cb('hi');
}

foo(arg => console.log(arg));
```

I'm hoping I can make this somehow work with subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible. There has been a discussion about it in this issue -  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373

Comment: Thank you for providing a reference. Hoping that one day this answer is no longer correct.